# best / any way to count escapes in glibc regex(7) / GNU sed / grep / egrep Regular Expressions?

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, posix

Given bash environment variable settings :

```
 $ declare -g bs=$'\\' bsbs=$'\\\\' q="'";
```

This Regular Expression will correctly match a sequence of single quote-("'")-ed text ,
where such text may contain escaped single quotes:

```
 "[${bs}${q}]((([^${bsbs}]?[^${bs}${q}])|(${bsbs}${bs}${q}))+)[${bs}${q}]"

 $ echo "[${bs}${q}]((([^${bsbs}]?[^${bs}${q}])|(${bsbs}${bs}${q}))+)[${bs}${q}]"
 [\']((([^\\]?[^\'])|(\\\'))+)[\']
```

(the backtick in "[\']" is not strictly required but is included for clarity,
and in case one is trying to encode this value in a singly-quoted string).

The problem lies in how best to generalize this for any escaped quoting character,
and how to handle runs of multiple escape sequences ;
ONLY if the run of input escape characters is of ODD ((n&1)==1) size (number of bytes),
then the last escape is ACTIVE, the last character is INACTIVE (part of string), and otherwise (number of escapes is EVEN ((n&1)==0), then the string contains HALF the
number of escapes (n>>1) and the last character is ACTIVE (ie. not escaped) .

Also, in sed and grep / egrep this has some issues :

o The matching sub-groups can occupy subsequent '\1+' group numbers, increasing their number - if any subsequent group does not match -

- ideally, I'd like to be able to express that regexp without any subgroups that can possibly affect subsequent sub-group numbers.

o It doesn't handle Number of Escapes at all, and will fail to
recognize that a quote that is proceeded by an EVEN number of
escapes is not escaped.

So my question is :

How best to solve these issues using only glibc-supported
POSIX REs or grep / sed REs ?

ie. allow arbitrary length sequences of escapes of ODD (effective escape) or EVEN (ineffective escape) length to be recognized inside RegExps ?

I really think POSIX REs could benefit from special syntax to handle such questions, like:

```
 [\\]{1,}\#&1\?$A\:$B
```

Where '}#&1' means the test 'x & 1' on the number of elements matched by previous
[\]{...} group, and ?x:y means
"if last test is true, substitute x, otherwise y in RE".

Then one could actually easily express this and safely handle any number of escapes
in RegExp parsed strings .
How to do that without some new RE syntax like this ?

Very difficult, if not impossible / infeasible , with RegExp
exprs alone.

Or am I wrong ?

Is there now an easy way to do arithmetic on run length of previous group in modern POSIX REs ?

Example 1 :

```
$ declare -g bs=$'\\' bsbs=$'\\\\' q="'";

$ echo "'a quot\\'d string' 42" | sed -r 's/'"[${bs}${q}]((([^${bsbs}]?[^${bs}${q}])|(${bsbs}${bs}${q}))+)[${bs}${q}]"'[[:space:]]([0-9]+)/\1\t:\t\2/'
'a quot'd string    :   g
```

Example 2 :

```
$ echo "'a quot\\'d string' 42" | 
  sed -r 's/'"[${q}]((([^${bsbs}]?[^${q}])|(${bsbs}${q}))+)[${q}]"'[[:space:]]([0-9]+)/\1\t:\t\2/'
a quot\'d string    :   g
```

note how  the ${bs}-es @rowboat mentioned are removed, and still
the same result , as would using only $bs, not $bsbs :

```
$ echo "'a quot\\'d string' 42" | sed -r 's/'"[${q}]((([^${bs}]?[^${q}])|(${bs}${q}))+)[${q}]"'[[:space:]]([0-9]+)/\1\t:\t\2/'
a quot\'d string    :   g
```

Conclusion :

I am developing non-POSIX extensions to the
"regex(7) - POSIX.2 regular expressions"
library, provided by glibc , and to PCRE, and to PERL,
and to cl-ppcre (SBCL's Common Lisp RE library) , and
to Emacs's RE library for :

o defining a meaning for any named POSIX character class when
suffixed by '-esc' or 'esc',
eg. '[[:spaceesc:]]' or '[^[:space-esc:]]' or '[[:quote-esc:]]' ,
which means:
A character that is ordinarily a member of character class 'X',
is not a member of character class "${X}esc" (a synonym of "${X}-esc")
IFF it is preceded by an ODD NUMBER of Escape Characters
('\':ASCII "\x5c").

```
 All character sequences that are subject to an :*esc: character
 class test will have legal '\\' , '\xXX', '\0OOO', or '\Uxxxxxx' or
'\uXXXX' sequences replaced by :
 ASCII:\x5c , ASCII:\xXX (where XX are hex digits), 
 ASCII:\OOO (where OOO are Octal digits) ,
 24-bit unicode value with code point xxxxxx (x: hex digit) , and
 16-bit unicode value with code point xxxx (x: hex digit) ,
 respectively.

 Also '[[:quote:]]' and '[[:quoteesc:]]' classes must be
 supported that select characters (or non-escaped chars)
 with the Unicode 'Quotation Mark' binary attribute, and
 '[[:punct:]]' or '[[:punctesc:]]' would similarly apply
 to all (non-escaped) chars which have the Punctuation attribute.

 Perhaps a similar '*cesc' or '*escc' character class suffixes
 could be provided that support also the C escapes:
  '\n','\r','\t','\v','\b','\l'... etc.

 If the / (\U1D566) flag is specified / UNICODE_NAMES flag,
 then Unicode Names can also be specified :
  \U1D566 == \U{MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK SMALL U}
          == \U{MATHEMATICAL_DOUBLE_STRUCK_SMALL_U}
          .

 There is no point in doing such an exercise unless UTF-8 names
 also are supported, IMHO .

 There no point in just handling escaped spaces if full escape
 handling is not also enable-able somehow or comes along with it.

 Actually, the SBCL Pure-Common-Lisp implementation is about
 the speediest and nicest to use amongst ANY RE implementation
 I have used , and already supports escaped classes & Unicode
 Names.

 The LIBC regex and glob implementations are EXTRA-ORDINARILY SLOW!

 This slows down BASH and command-line tools and all tools that
 use the POSIX RE library, such as Flex / Bison / Yacc,
 tremendously .

 Perhaps either :
 A) Techniques used in SBCL PPCRE, libppcre, and PERL RE library
    can be ported to LIBC Regex library, in a new 'Fast Regex'
    replacement that can optionally replace old implementation
    on demand ;
 B) LIBC RE library can be made to transparently replace itself
    with libppcre or to a connection to a running SBCL instance
    with CL-PPCRE loaded, or to PERL with full PERL RE support,
    to support a UNIX CMSG Message API for Compiling, 
    Match Against String, or Match against FD / stream API, 
    and for Retrieval of Match Numbered N or with Name N,
    where N is in a set of Group Names or 
    Numbers sent in advance as identifying parenthesis groups,
    and which can contain multiple dimensions (numbers in square
    brackets) to denote sub-expressions.

 Also I think that supporting a char-class LENGTH test, of the
 form:
   ']{x,}\#<test>\?<A>\:<B>' , meaning:
 "  If number of characters in character-class just closed
    satisfies test <test> , then RE fragment <A> is parsed / takes
    effect, else RE <B> takes effect.
 ", would be very useful - for <test> in:
 {=X,>X,<X,<=X,>=X,&X,|X,^X,&~X,|~X} , where X is a decimal number.

 But first, I am working on the escaped char-classes support.
```

I can't understand why no-one seems to understand what I was suggesting with this question.

I hope the above makes things clearer.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to develop & submit some sort of patch to glibc Regexps to be able to have, as a GNU extension, some kind of Previous { .. } Group Number of Elements Referral, ('}\#') and Test / Arithmetic, and Conditional Expressions inside REs - 
I could really use such a thing right now .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some example inputs and what you are expecting as output. Show us what kind of things you are trying to match. It is extremely hard to parse that regex without such examples.

Comment: @terdon : OK , thanks, will do.

Comment: Also, you mention "POSIX RE" (which presumably means Basic Regular Expressions, BRE) but also mention GNU grep which supports Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) but also Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE). Please clarify which regex language you are actually interested in. I am pretty sure you know significantly more about this than I do, but I still think you could clarify a bit and it isn't just my own ignorance that is confusing me.

Comment: BTW `[\']` matches on backslash or single quotation mark, so your expression matches `\foo'`, ``'foo\``, ``\foo\`` and `'foo'`

Comment: @rowboat: yes, in previous invesgtigations of this, I did not have "\\'" in ${q} prefix & suffix, 
and it worked better, but as I mentioned in text, in order to enclose in any single quoted string you need backslash, and if in double quotes a single backslash is replaced by the char it escapes. Will ammend RE accordingly in Example # 2.

Comment: @rowboat: the end-of-line escaping by '\' provided by grep / sed / bash will suffice -
this should be done before text gets pattern-matched .

Comment: I can't make much sense of what you're asking. Maybe you can start by clarifying what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: FWIW, POSIX EREs have no back-references. POSIX BREs do. GNU BRE and ERE do except in GNU awk.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : I an trying to find the easiest / simplest / most elegant way 
of getting Shell scripts  to parse strings into tuples that contain singly or doubly quoted
strings, is all - consider : 
       $  declare my_mbrs="'a quot\'d string' 42";
       $  declare -a my_arr=($my_mbrs);
       $  declare -p my_arr
       declare -a my_arr=([0]="'a" [1]="quot\\'d" [2]="string'" [3]="42")
I am trying to develop the right sed expression so I can say : 
      declare -a my_arr=($(echo "$my_mbrs"| sed -n "$X"))
and I will get the correct (my_arr[0]=="a quot'd string" my_arr[1]==42

Comment: Doing `arr=( $str )` or `arr=( $(cmd) )`  does split+glob on the contents of `$str` (or the output of `cmd`), quotes are not involved in that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : yes, I know, there was not enough room in previous comment to say
that of course in that context I am using an "IFS=$'\x09'" setting, so bash will split $my_arr only on "\t" / tabs, but still where should my sed script insert the tabs ?
If it cannot determine in the expression exactly how long is the preceding sequence of escapes, or if this is an ODD or EVEN number .

Comment: One could imagine, after processing the RE character sequence  ']{X,}', that the
compiler / matcher  knows how many elements have matched the whole 
 '[$class]{$at_least,$at_most}' group ;
so, why not let programmers, with a new syntax, refer and react to this known number somehow ? Like '\#<expr>' to perform a test on that number ?
And then being able to conditionally include $A if test succeeds, $B if it fails, in RE ?
Yes, maybe old-style Back-References can be used - but I'd like to allow any program
to using the glibc POSIX regexp library to handle quoted strings OK.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates all your needs so we can best help you. Focus on WHAT you want to do rather than HOW you're trying to do it.

Comment: In `echo "'a quot\\'d string' 42"` - is `\\'` intended to be an escaped `'` or an escaped ```\``` followed by a `'`? If the former, why do you have 2 ```\```s before the `'`? If the latter, doesn't that make it an invalid string as it has an odd number of unescaped `'`s?

Comment: @EdMorton : In bash shell, Double-Quoted strings can contain Escapes : 
  $ declare s="'a quot\\'d string' 42"; 
  $  declare -p s
  declare -- s="'a quot\\'d string' 42"
  $ echo $s
  'a quot\'d string' 42

I think this is a source of the confusion, since zsh / ksh would have different behaviour.

Comment: @JVD I know strings can contain escapes, I just don't know what you intended doubling them to mean as described in my comment. I'm not confused by any behavior ksh or zsh might have, just wanted to know what you intended your bash code to do. I see `echo $s` in your comment instead of `echo "$s"` - is that the intent of the double escapes, so you can remove the quotes that should be around `"$s"` and have one escape left after bash consumes one of them?

Answer (score 4):

If the point is to tokenise shell code the same way the shell language interpreter does, regexps will get you nowhere.

The zsh shell exposes its tokeniser with the `z` parameter expansion flag (or `Z` which can take options to process comments or change the treatment of newline) which you can combine with the `Q` parameter expansion to do quote removal.

For instance:

```
tokens() printf ' - « %s »\n' ${(Z[Cn])1}
tokens_dequoted() printf ' - « %s »\n' "${(@Q)${(Z[Cn])1}}"
```

Would report all the shell tokens in its first argument, dropping comments; the second one also removing one layer of quoting:

```
$ tokens '  foo "a b"; "" "$(echo "x y")" <<'"'qwe '\''qwe' #qwe"
 - « foo »
 - « "a b" »
 - « ; »
 - « "" »
 - « "$(echo "x y")" »
 - « << »
 - « 'qwe '\''qwe' »
$ tokens_dequoted '  foo "a b"; "" "$(echo "x y")" <<'"'qwe '\''qwe' #qwe"
 - « foo »
 - « a b »
 - « ; »
 - «  »
 - « $(echo "x y") »
 - « << »
 - « qwe 'qwe »
```

You can see that in order to do the same, you need to implement a full shell parser.

You can get somewhere with regexp if you reduce the scope: only consider `'...'`, `"..."`, and `\` types of quotes (not `$'...'`), and only whitespace as delimiter and ignore expansions inside double quotes. In bash 4.4+, which contrary to zsh can't handle NUL bytes in its code anyway, and with GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
tokens() {
  local tokens
  readarray -td '' tokens < <(printf %s "$1" |
    grep -Ezo '(\\.|[^[:space:]\\"'\'']|'\''[^'\'']*'\''|"(\\.|[^\\"])*")+'
  )
  printf ' - « %s »\n' "${tokens[@]}"
}
```

Then:

```
$ tokens ' foo "a b"\c\\\" c\ d '" 'qwe'\''qwe'\"'\"qwe"
 - « foo »
 - « "a b"\c\\\" »
 - « c\ d »
 - « 'qwe'\''qwe'"'"qwe »
```

To remove one layer of quoting from that, I'd resort to `perl` (or `zsh` which can do that out of the box as seen above).

Comment: I am NOT interested in getting programs other than sed / grep / POSX extended REs 
to work.

Incidentally :  
    $ tokens_dequoted() printf ' - « %s »\n' "${(@Q)${(Z[Cn])1}}"

$ IFS=$'\x09'; tokens_dequoted "'A \' B\'"$'\x09'42; unset IFS;
 - « A \ »
 - « B' »
 - « 42 »
$ 

which is not what we want. 

Yes, I know about readarray - it has same problem using delim $'\x09' and quotes .
I'd like to work on making an extension to glibc regexps and globs that handle these Quoted String cases, and also correctly allow the delimiter itself (eg. $'\x09' ) to be escaped , as well as 's.

Answer (score -3):

A better answer: use pcre / PERL RegExps :

```
$ cat a.pcre
/^[']((?|(?:[^\\]?[^'\t\n\r])|(?:[\\]['\t\n\r]))*)[']\t((?|(?:[^\\]?[^\t])|(?:[\\][^\t\n\r]))+)/
'A quot\'d\ tab containing string'  42

$ pcretest < a.pcre 
PCRE version 8.45 2021-06-15

re> data>  0: 'A quot'd\x09tab containing string'\x0942
1: A quot'd\x09tab containing string
2: 42
data>
```

Comment: [You said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765449/best-any-way-to-count-escapes-in-glibc-regex7-gnu-sed-grep-egrep-regul#comment1459662_765467) "I am NOT interested in getting programs other than sed / grep / POSX extended REs to work." and then posted this answer using a program other than sed / grep / POSX extended REs.

Comment: Yes, but this was just an illustratory / exemplary answer, AFTER I had reached the final
conclusion "No, there is no built-in way in GLIBC POSIX or in GNU grep / sed REs to
handle an even/odd number of escape characters properly" .

Comment: After thinking about this for the last 3 days or so, I have reached the conclusion to develop a patch for both glibc and libc6 and grep and sed,  that , for every POSIX character class,
 as a new GNU extension that can be enabled with the '/E' 
 "Provide Escaped Char.Classes" modifier flag, will also provide an 'esc' suffixed variant of the char class that won't treat chars preceded by an ODD number of escapes as being part of the class, and maybe which will also have the sort of "number of elements test and conditional expression" logic described above.

Comment: The PCRE answer is a non-answer to this specific question, but illustrates the sort of solution
that would be acceptable, if only we could do something as simple or simpler in POSIX / grep 
/ sed RegExps , but we can't.

Comment: What's the point if you can already do whatever it is you want to do using perl? FWIW I still don't know what it is you're trying to do. If you provided sample input/output in your question that demonstrated all your requirements you may get an answer using existing POSIX tools and maybe it's not necessary to use a single regexp.

Comment: Because PCRE is not linked to by default by GLIBC, bash / shells, grep, and sed, 
meaning I'd have to depend on a particular distro providing a modern PCRE library,
or ship the PCRE library, or build it, or prompt the user to install it ... 
I don't want to get into that.  My question was specifically about glibc ,/ libc6 grep & sed REs, these tools need to be installed on EVERY kind of modern POSIX compliant system, including BSD / UNIX-es .

Comment: Not all POSIX systems have GNU tools so creating a new GNU extension won't solve that problem and it sounds like a problem that doesn't need to be solved as there's other ways to do what I think you might want with existing tools/functionality.

Comment: All I am trying to do is find the best way to parse streams of Row lines that may 
contain quoted strings that  may contain Escaped Quote or Separator chars,
only in GLIBC / lbc6 POSIX or GNU sed / grep compatible REs - there isn't a nice easy
answer.

Comment: Be wary of creating extensions to be able to do things more briefly as that leads to code bloat and eventually https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13. Whatever it is you want to be able to do I guarantee we could do today with awk on ANY Unix box. Not using a single regexp but who cares and anyway [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Comment: @EdMorton : no, but if necessary, as one of my "Required Tools" Dependencies, it would be very easy to build in advance builds of modern GNU grep / sed for AIX  / z/OS  / HP-UX / 
BSD / MacOSX whatever, and direct the user to install them. If users now have to install PCRE as well, this is getting too much. Much better to develop a patch, that, if all test cases continue to pass, might be accepted and make it into all modern glibc / shell / grep / sed builds, and which I can at least use on my machines.

Comment: And you're not interested in seeing if there's an existing solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve that doesn't use a single regexp but might be completely fine?

Comment: No, it's not that I'm not interested, it's that the solution I need is for GLIBC or libc6 supported RegExps .
Ultimately, I am trying to develop a RegExp & Glob library in C that provides optimal
interfaces to be used from C, C++, Java, picoLisp or SBCL Common LISP code 
; it would be best to be able to use and depend on just the RegExp and Glob facilities
provided by the LIBC in use and not some other library. Then, optionally, PCRE support
could be added at a later stage. The point is, LIBC's regexp code is in EVERY executable,
what's the point if it is slow & useless ?

Comment: It is not that I did not know how to solve this problem by other means when I asked the
question, I just wanted to confirm my suspicion that GLIBC + grep  + sed RegExps 
cannot alone be used to solve it, as they currently are.

Comment: And there is no 'pcresed' tool shipped or built as part of pcre, alas .

Comment: Probably, development of a 'pcresed' tool would be a useful addition to my work list.

Comment: sed doesn't support PCREs so it's not obvious what a tool named `pcresed` would do.